# python yaml "display" is not defined

Tags: python

i tried to make my yolov8 custom data while i tried to convert file data to yaml, i got error on `display()` function

```
import yaml

data = {
    "train": "hat-data/train/images",
    "val": "hat-data/valid/images",
    "test": "hat-data/test/images",
    "names": ["hat", "nohat"],
    "nc": 7,
}

with open("hat-data.yaml", "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)

with open("hat-data.yaml", "r") as f:
    hatdata = yaml.safe_load(f)
    **display**(hatdata)
```

error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/xx/xxx/script.py", line 16, in <module>
    display(hatdata)
    ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'display' is not defined
```

What i tried

1. reinstall package
2. change value

how to solve this error?

Comment: Where do you think `display` is coming from? There's no such global function in Python.